# DevExpress RepositoryItemTextEdit Appearance TextOptions WordWrap=Wrap not working

Tags: devexpress, word-wrap, textedit

When I go into the In-Place Editor Repository and set the WordWrap property = Wrap on a TextEdit (it is being used as the editor in the Vertical Grid) there is no wrapping at runtime. The text tickertapes instead.

My users are clamoring for wordwrap, and they also want to see the text in the field too --not like the MemoExEdit which displays a two-state icon: "empty" and "has some text" and the user only gets to see the text when they give the editor focus.

Is it possible to get wordwrap on an in-place TextEdit? Or is that property setting ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextEdit` is a single-line editor.

You should use `MemoEdit` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The MemoExEdit can be used as well. Simply set the ShowIcon property to false and the text in the field will be displayed instead of the icon.

Comment: thanks for that tip!  (Unfortunately I can only flag an answer as "the answer"-- Stackoverflow won't let me upvote a helpful answer because I am unregistered.)